# JScrollPane formatting to show Pascals Triangle

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

so I want to make my Jscrollpane to show Pascals triangle. I have this:

```
labelPanel= new JPanel();
lRows = new JLabel[n];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    lRows[i]=new JLabel(Arrays.toString(tri.tri[i]));
    labelPanel.add(lRows[i]);
}
```

But it's not what I want and I am not sure how to fix that, picture included. Any help?

[image: Painted!]

Comment: What's tri.tri? Does it hold Strings? Append new lines and spaces as needed to the Strings within tri.tri? You can always just create a String yourself from looping over tri.tri and adding spaces and newlines as needed.

Comment: tri.tri[i] is i'th pascals triangle row with integers, but I can handle that, I mainly want it to look like on the first pic, so that every line is centered and there is just 1 row in each line

Comment: That's information you'll need to provide in your question. To answer it, you'll have to then loop over your array yourself and add spaces and new lines as needed to a StringBuilder, and then toString your StringBuilder to get the String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `JPanel` uses a flow layout. To get the vertical arrangement you are looking for, you should be able to do this by using a `BoxLayout` with a vertical orientation on your `labelPanel`, then add your `JLabel` rows.

```
labelPanel= new JPanel();
//set this up to order things vertically
labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
lRows = new JLabel[n];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    lRows[i]=new JLabel(Arrays.toString(tri.tri[i]));
    //to center your label, just set the X alignment
    lRows[i].setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT)
    labelPanel.add(lRows[i]);
}
```

I also threw in a line to center the rows like your picture. `Component` comes from the `java.awt` package.

You can read up on the different layout managers available by default in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how would I go about centering each row just like it is on the pic?

Comment: @user3369008 Check out the edit, I added a line that should center things for you

Comment: Thanks, that's EXACTLY what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to rotate the triangle to make it look like:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1

1   2   3   4   5   6   

1   3   6   10  15  

1   4   10  20   

1   5   15  

1   6   

1
```

However, if you must print sth like this [image: myTriangle]

I did it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<Triangle.trojkat[i].length; j++){
        sb.append(Triangle.trojkat[i][j]);
        len = String.valueOf(Triangle.trojkat[i][j]).length();
        while (12-len>0){
            sb.append(" ");
            len++;
        }
        //sb.append(" ");
    }
    TriangleRes[i] = new JLabel(sb.toString(), JLabel.CENTER);
    TriangleRes[i].setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,8));
sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Let me explain:
I decided, that I want my triangle print beautifuly for the size smaller that 35. Then I've checked, that the numbers in such a triangle come up to 10 digits. Then, when I added next number to the existing row, I checked it's length and while total length wasn't 12 yet, I add spaces. This lead to the triangle that you have attached on the picture.

If this is for Ph.D Macyna classes, just post a question on a group and I'll respond :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a JTextArea
2. Give it a monospaced font, i.e., Font.MONOSPACED
3. Append your lines of text to the JTextArea, similar to how you'd do this in the console.
4. Put the JTextArea into a JScrollPane
5. Voilà. You're done.

   ---
6. If you need to use JLabels, then put them in a JPanel that uses GridLayout with enough columns to show your bottom row.
7. If you did this, you'd be putting empty JLabels in every other cell, so that the cells branch correctly.