# Java GUI Pascal Triangle Vertical Align

Tags: java, css, swing, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a Pascal Triangle program where I type a row number and it makes a triangle with number of rows that I want. Let's say I type '7', then it makes triangle with 7 rows, each row is a JLabel. Problem is the text looks ugly, you can't see for example that 4+6 in row 4 is 10 in row 5 etc. I have no idea how to make it work, any ideas? I can change the output method for let's say Text Area or something like that, I just want it to work.

Comment: One solution: use a JTextArea, and set its Font to `Font.MONOSPACED`. Then append your text to the JTextArea similar to how you'd println it out to console.

Comment: Or use BoxLayout as per the [solution in this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278691/jscrollpane-formatting-to-show-pascals-triangle).